# SwiftUI dropDestination for URL, duplicates?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

On macOS 13.2, Xcode 14.2 :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Drop files over here!").font(.largeTitle)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        
            .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { urls, _ in
                
                for u in urls {
                    print(u.lastPathComponent)
                }

                return true
            }
    }
}
```

prints duplicates, I can't figure why. Is this normal behavior (or rather a bug)?

Comment: I see the same, whatever the `payloadType`